# add css styles if switch is enabled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, laravel

I have a table to which I add images

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blog_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->BigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('image', 128);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

In this table, I add a column in which you can change the value of true or false

```
$table->boolean('border')->default(true);
```

Then in the controller, I will add a switch so that I can change this value

```
protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new BlogImage());
     
        $grid->column('border', __('Border'))->switch();

        $grid->column('image', __('Image'))->image();

        return $grid;
    }
```

Everything should be clear with this, I have a field that I switch and in the database in this field the value is either 0 or 1

Next, I display these images on the page

```
@foreach($blog_images as $blog_image)
<div class="main-image">
  <img src="/storage/{{ $blog_image->image }}">
</div>
@endforeach
```

And here I have a main-image class that has the following styles:

```
.main-image {
    position: relative;

    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    &::before {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid red;
    }
  }
```

Here I have style `border: 3px solid red;`

And I need to make it so that when the border field is true, this style is applied to this class, if it is false, then it should not be accordingly

But I don't have any idea where to do it yet

Is it possible to do this in the controller or do I need to use javascript. How to do it better here?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you getting `$blog_images->border` in blade file?

Comment: Locked due to [edit abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75524915/revisions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by checking `$blog_image->border` to add a second class if true.

```
@foreach($blog_images as $blog_image)
<div class="main-image{{ $blog_image->border ? ' main-image-border' : '' }}">
  <img src="/storage/{{ $blog_image->image }}">
</div>
@endforeach
```

Remove the border from your original `main-image` and add `main-image-border` like below.

```
.main-image {
    position: relative;

    img {
      width: 100%;
    }
    &::before {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 3px solid red;
    }
}

.main-image-border {
    &::before {
        border: 3px solid red;
    }
}
```

Now, all of the image containing divs will have the `main-image` class, and only those with the border property as true will receive `main-image-border` and get the red border applied.

Comment: What if my css looks like this `.main-image { position: relative;
    img { width: 100%; }
    &::before { display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; } }` Will this have any effect?

Comment: I checked, this class is added, but due to before it is not applied in any way. Here I need to somehow interact with before

Comment: I corrected it in the post, I just initially showed my css wrong. Sorry

Comment: @brokenheart see my edit - try the updated CSS which uses `before`.